# Remove "Template Notebook" header?

Tags: user-interface

I'm not sure how this happened, but all of a sudden my notebook has an extra "Template Notebook" header, see screenshot:

[image]

I'd like to remove this header and go back to the regular notebook layout.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just do the following in your notebook:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    {CellContext->"Global`", DockedCells->{}, ShowCellTags->False, TaggingRules->{}}
]
```